# Using Sourcing operator to select multiple criteria

Tags: powershell

With in powershell I am using the '.' after a variable to select the .name of the variable results. Is there a way to select multiple  criteria with this, such as .length.

I am using `$localitem.Name`, that returns
20240208.zip

But I would like to use something like this `$localitem.Name and .Length`
So the result would be 20240208.zip | 1028

---

In know I can use select object and go about it that way, but just wanted to see if the above was an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

It just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

The most concise solution is probably the following, which uses the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```
# Sample item
$localItem = Get-Item $PROFILE

# Note: NO SPACE before "{"
#       .ForEach({ $localItem.$_ }) works too.
('Name', 'Length').ForEach{ $localItem.$_ }
```

By contrast, using `select` ([`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)), e.g.  `$localItem | select Name, Length` returns a *single object* that has both a `.Name` and a `.Length` property.
(There is `-ExpandProperty` to get just a property *value*, but that only works with *one* property.)

To make the typing of the above a little less cumbersome, you can use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) to provide the property names, albeit at the expense of performance:

```
(Write-Output Name Length).ForEach{ $localItem.$_ }
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but if the OP wants a VERTICAL LINE delimited string, `('Name','Length').ForEach{$i.$_} -join '|'` could be used.

Comment: Good point, @lit. I didn't spell it out, because I didn't think they _literally_ wanted that, and were just looking for the individual values.